# Ajax call stripping out the inline css from my div html

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I am using ajax URL for extracting the HTML from a link but the response stripping out the inline CSS from my div class.

I am using this below code. it is only extracting HTML code but not the inline CSS.

Expecting result is all the HTML code with inline Style CSS

```
$ = jQuery;
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a.page-numbers").click(function(event)
{    
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
    url:$(this).attr("href"),
    type:'GET',
    success: function(data)
    {

        console.log($(data).find('#news').html());      
    }

  });
});
});
```

expecting result is getting code with all inline style css.

```
<div class="sm-grid sm-effect" id="sm-grid-layout" style="position: 
relative; height: 469.149px;">
```

Whereas I am getting result without inline CSS

```
<div class="sm-grid sm-effect" id="sm-grid-layout">
```

Comment: Edit the question and put the clarifications there, not in comments.

Comment: is the inline css from the other site added programmatically?

Comment: `success` is called if your ajax request succeeds and the data returned by the server will be available in `data` of the function.

Comment: jQuery doesn't remove the inline styles. Are you sure they're in `data`? Please show the output of `console.log(data)`.

Comment: @Barmar 
this is the result I am getting on console.log(data)
part of some console.log result
"<div class="sm-grid sm-effect" id="sm-grid-layout">  

            
            
            <div class="grid-sm-boxes-in post-2913">
               <div class="grid-sm-border">
                  
"

Comment: @Barmar whereas If I go to inspect element I can see the inline css with style tag at frontend.

Comment: Where is `id="news"` in that `data`?

Comment: You probably have other JavaScript that's adding the inline style, that's what you see when you inspect the element.

Comment: @BarmarI think you are right. I just checked the data response. It is extracting the inline CSS of other divs. There must be another javaScript maybe.
can you please tell me how can I find that JavaScript and get the CSS from it. Any further help would be appreciated